# Usage of split with semicolon

Tags: split, tcl

When I am chasing my work with `Tcl` code, surprised by the below code's output.

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh
puts [split {a:b:c:d} :]
puts [split {a;b;c;d} ;]
puts [split {a-b-c-d} -]
puts [split {a b c d} ]; # 'space' will be taken as split-char here.
```

**Output:**

```
a b c d
{a;b;c;d;}
a b c d
a b c d
```

As you can see,    `{a;b;c;d;}` is a list with one element.

With semi-colon as the separator character, `split` is returning the whole input as one single element-ed list instead of providing each word as each element for that list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A semicolon is also an optional statement end indicator.

Try:

```
 puts [split {a;b;c;d} {;}]
```

I'm wondering why it didn't give a syntax error though.

Comment: Thanks Brad. I forgot that. But, i didn't get any error.

Comment: The thing inside `[`brackets`]` is a _script_. A semicolon is an entirely reasonable thing to put in there.

Comment: I see...so it is parsed sort of outside in rather than left to right. `puts [split {a;b;c;d} {;} ; # semis are special] \n
]`

Comment: No, it's parsed left-to-right. It's just that a bare semicolon at that point in a script is interpreted as a command separator. If you want it not be to interpreted as a command separator, you wrap it in braces (`{;}`) or escape it with a backslash (`\;`).